# How can we test if a device is secured?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage

To work with, the device has to be lock with a pin or password. How can I check if the device has a pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the error callback function of the Secure Storage init. If you reach the error callback, the device is probably not secured with a pin:

```
ss = new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage(
    function () {
        console.log('OK');
    },
    function () {
        console.log('NOT SECURED!');
    },
    'my_app');
```

You can even let the user secure the device directly:

```
ss.secureDevice(
    function () {
        console.log('OK');
    },
    function () {
        console.log('NOT OK');
    }
);
```

Comment: When using 'WhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly' your code above will always return 'OK' on iOS. Tested it on 2 devices, 1 with and 1 without lockscreen.